# libvncserver / libvncclient websocket support (to vSphere)?

Tags: c++, websocket, vmware, remote-desktop, vnc

I am trying to use **libvnc** to write client application for **VMware ESXi 6** vm's consoles.
From ESXi 6 VMware provides **websocket** for this purpose. They are also released basic HTML5 client for this.

ESXi websocket VNC uses connection path to authorize.
When HTML5 client trying to connect it making request like this:
**wss://*esxi_host_ip*/ticket/*secret_token***

From my research I know that this method also works with noVNC Client
(https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC)
**This client passes "path" parameter to RFB implementation.**

From libvnc website I know that it support websockets but I don't know if it is supported on client side and if the answer is **YES**, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the answer is **NO** but simple hack is possible.

**Connection to websocket vnc server from libvnc is not directly possible.**

As solution for my problem I used custom made **tcp** to **websocket** proxy where I firstly negotiating websocket connection and then connecting standard tcp vnc client.